# How to stop Ajax success(response) from showing the entire html structure on my <div> element

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am building a user logon system on my website. My code works fine with no problems. See the the reset password Ajax request.

> html

```
<div id="forgotPass"></div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
                     $(document).ready(function(){
                     $("#forgotBtn").click(function(event){
                     if ($("#forgotForm")[0].checkValidity()){
                    event.preventDefault();

                    $("#forgotBtn").val('Validating...');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'assets/php/action.php',
                        method: 'post',
                        data: $('#forgotForm').serialize()+'&action=forgot',
                        success:function(response){
                        //console.log(response);
                        $("#forgotBtn").val('Reset Password');
                        $("#forgotForm")[0].reset();
                        $('#forgotPass').html(response);         
                        }
                                });     
                               }
                            });

                         });

                   </script>
```

> PHP

```
//Error or Success Message Alert
        public function messageShow($type, $message){
            return '<div class="alert alert-'.$type. ' alert-dismissible">
                        <button type="button" class="close"
                        data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        <strong class="text-center">'.$message.'</strong>
                    </div>';
        }
// FORGOT PASSWORD AJAX HANDLE =========================================

    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'forgot'){
        $email = $user->test_input($_POST['email']);

        $user_found = $user->currentUser($email);

        if ($user_found != null) {
            $token = uniqid();
            $token = str_shuffle($token);

            $user->forgot_password($token,$email);
            //Server settings
            try {
            
            // Eable verbose debug output
                $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;  
             // Send using SMTP
                $mail->isSMTP();
            //Set the SMTP server to send through
                 $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
             //Enable SMTP authentication
                 $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
             //SMTP username
                 $mail->Username   = Database::USERNAME;
             // SMTP password
                 $mail->Password   = Database::PASSWORD;
             //Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
                 $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
             // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
                 $mail->Port       = 587; 

            //Local Code from from Ajax Request & public class
                 $mail->setFrom(Database::USERNAME, 'CShare Support');
                 $mail->addAddress($email);

                 $mail->isHTML(true);
                 $mail->Subject = 'Reset Password';
                 $mail->Body = '<h3>Click the below link to reset your password. Attention: This link will expire in 10 minutes!<br><a href="http://localhost/crypt.v4/reset-pass.php?email='.$email. '&token='.$token.'"><br><br><h1 class="text-center font-weignt-bold text-primary">RESET PASSWORD</h1></a><br><br><br>Regards<br><br>CShare Support.</h3>';
                 
                 $mail->send();
                 echo $user->messageShow('success', 'We have send you password reset link, Please check you email!');
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
            echo $user->messageShow('danger', 'Something went wrong please try again later!');
            }

        }
        else{
            echo $user->messageShow('info', 'This email is not registered!');
        }
    }
```

The problem is after a successful reset password. The div show my #forgotPass response plus the entire html structure.  Why is that and how to stop it. Thanks.
**See the below html structure displayed in my div**

```
2021-01-26 15:57:02 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP bk2sm10065994ejb.98 - gsmtp
2021-01-26 15:57:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2021-01-26 15:57:03 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [41.60.79.136]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2021-01-26 15:57:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2021-01-26 15:57:03 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2021-01-26 15:57:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2021-01-26 15:57:03 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [41.60.79.136]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2021-01-26 15:57:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2021-01-26 15:57:04 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2021-01-26 15:57:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-01-26 15:57:04 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2021-01-26 15:57:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-01-26 15:57:04 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Accepted
2021-01-26 15:57:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<arnoxmariaz@gmail.com>
2021-01-26 15:57:04 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 OK bk2sm10065994ejb.98 - gsmtp
2021-01-26 15:57:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<ali820@outlook.com>
2021-01-26 15:57:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 OK bk2sm10065994ejb.98 - gsmtp
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2021-01-26 15:57:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Go ahead bk2sm10065994ejb.98 - gsmtp
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2021 16:57:02 +0100
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: ali820@outlook.com
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: CShare Support <arnoxmariaz@gmail.com>
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Reset Password
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <edsX5pKq7hoxltVhdTOMZiuWIfyivvbs3ISNHmvFP30@localhost>
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.2.0 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: <h3>Click the below link to reset your password. Attention: This link will expire in 10 minutes!<br><a href="http://localhost/crypt.v4/reset-pass.php?email=alio820@outlook.com&token=b03333e6c1601"><br><br><h1 class="text-center font-weignt-bold text-primary">RESET PASSWORD</h1></a><br><br><br>Regards<br><br>CShare Support.</h3>
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2021-01-26 15:57:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2021-01-26 15:57:06 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 OK 1611676628 bk2sm10065994ejb.98 - gsmtp
2021-01-26 15:57:06 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2021-01-26 15:57:06 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection bk2sm10065994ejb.98 - gsmtp
×We have send you password reset link, Please check you email!
```

I do not all this to be displayed in my div. But only the massageShow = 'We have send you password reset link', 'Please check you email!'

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the issue here; you're saying that this entire log output is displayed?

Comment: `$('#forgotPass').html(response)` will put the HTML from `response` inside div id="forgotPass". Just remove this line.

Comment: yes that is true. all of it in the div

Comment: @FelippeDuartee the forgotPass is used to display a massage coming from a massageShow function i created in a <?php> script  that is  'We have send you password reset link', 'Please check you email !'

Comment: So the issue is inside PHP code, not JS. Please include the code of the PHP script that outputs this message.

Comment: Ok let me edit the question to add the php code

Comment: It seems as though the SMTP debugging is being immediately output. If you comment out the line `$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;`, do you still get all this?

Comment: @El_Vanja thanks man, hahaha, that was the issue. the SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER was the problem and of course it was supposed to be doing that. Thanks you are life saver, rather SERVER lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though the SMTP debugging is being immediately output. If you comment out the line $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;,
After commenting out the line; Case has been resolved.

Credits to El_Vanja